# Clarity issue in tikzpictures

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(4,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(4,4){C}
\tkzDefPoint(0,4){D}
\tkzLabelPoints[left](A,D)
\tkzLabelPoints[right](B,C)
\tkzDrawSegment[](A,B)
\tkzDrawSegment[](B,C)
\tkzDrawSegment[](C,D)
\tkzDrawSegment[](A,D)
\tkzLabelSegment[below left=5pt, xshift=7mm](A,B){}
\tkzLabelSegment[ left=5pt, xshift=13mm](B,C){}
\tkzLabelSegment[above left=5pt, xshift=7mm](C,D){}
\tkzLabelSegment[ left=5pt, xshift=0mm](A,D){}
\tkzMarkRightAngle(A,B,C)
\tkzMarkRightAngle(B,C,D)
\tkzMarkRightAngle(C,D,A)
\tkzMarkRightAngle(D,A,B)
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(5,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(7,4){C}
\tkzDefPoint(2,4){D}
\tkzLabelPoints[left](A,D)
\tkzLabelPoints[right](B,C)
\tkzDrawSegment(A,B)
\tkzDrawSegment(C,D)
\tkzDrawSegment(D,A)
\tkzDrawSegment(B,C)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In the first picture I draw a square, its a clear and perfect but when I am trying to draw quadrilateral, then getting that two sides namely BC and AD are not clear, I mean look dim. So what is the problem? I guess it might be length issue but could not find the solution.

Comment: Seems like a viewer issue and not related to `tikz` because BC and AD are inclined lines. Also the monitor plays a role in this. Print the pictures and you will see.

Comment: Or zooming sometimes shows it is just a viewer issue (even when print out is incorrect, sometimes).

Comment: What is your display viewer and you compile with what engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code
cfr is certainly right, perhaps a problem with the viewer because draw in tkz uses tikz command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,4/0/B,4/4/C,0/4/D}
%\tkzDrawSegments(A,B B,C C,D A,D)
\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C,D)
\tkzLabelPoints[left](A,D)
\tkzLabelPoints[right](B,C)
\tkzMarkRightAngles(A,B,C B,C,D C,D,A D,A,B)
\tkzLabelSegment[below left=5pt, xshift=7mm](A,B){$a$}
\tkzLabelSegment[ left=5pt, xshift=13mm](B,C){$b$}
\tkzLabelSegment[above left=5pt, xshift=7mm](C,D){$c$}
\tkzLabelSegment[ left=5pt](A,D){$d$}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,5/0/B,7/4/C,2/4/D}
\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C,D)
\tkzLabelPoints[left](A,D)
\tkzLabelPoints[right](B,C)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes it works i can find clear picture in a hard copy.

Comment: thanks a lot to all of you and a very special thanks to you sir Alain Mathhes.